# Portfolio Standard Deviation equation

Tags: standard-deviation

I'm trying to understand what this portfolio standard deviation equation means in the [slide screenshot as marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tssFf.png). If someone could help me explain how this equation works, that would be great.

When I read it, I read that standard deviation = (r- rf)/(r1 - rf) however I have no understanding on what the pipe symbols mean (do they mean absolute) or what theta(return1) means after the last pipe symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe symbol is absolute value. The slide, however, is gibberish.